# Getting non-const type in template

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class that can (and sometimes has to) take a `const` type, but there is a method that returns a new instance of the class with the same type, but should be explicitly non-const. For example, the following code fails to compile

```
template<class T> class SomeClass {
public:
    T val;
    SomeClass(T val) : val(val) {}
    SomeClass<T> other() {
        return SomeClass<T>(val);
    }
};

int main() {
    SomeClass<const int> x(5);
    SomeClass<int> y = x.other();
    return 0;
}
```

because even though there's a copy on val during the constructor, it's copying to the same type - `const int`. Just like you can distinguish between `T` and `const T` in a template, is there a way to distinguish between `T` and "`nonconst T`"?

Comment: I've never heard that you could use a `const` modifier in a template parameter like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SomeClass<typename std::remove_const<T>::type> other()
{
    return SomeClass<typename std::remove_const<T>::type>(val);
}
```

`std::remove_const` is from `<type_traits>` and is C++11. There's probably a `boost::remove_const` in Boost.TypeTraits, or you can even roll your own. It's also possible to use `std::remove_cv`.

Comment: There's probably a `std::tr1::remove_const` in a sufficiently new compiler if you don't want C++11.

Comment: Yes, there is a `boost::remove_const` in TypeTraits.

Comment: `<type_traits>`, while appears on my system (in boost, tr1, and C++11 variants) compiling with `clang++` and `g++` says it's not found. Regardless, a peak at the source got me the definition of std::remove_const, which worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can either use `std::remove_const` if you are using c++ 11. Otherwise, you can use this:

```
struct <typename T>
struct remove_const
{
    typedef T type;
};
struct <typename T>
struct remove_const<const T>
{
    typedef T type;
};
```

Which does the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in essence, is that there are two distinct types which are not strictly convertible.

You can use/return `std::remove_const` from type_traits:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
class SomeClass {
public:
    T val;
    SomeClass(T p) : val(p) {
    }

    SomeClass<typename std::remove_const<T>::type> other() {
        return static_cast<SomeClass<typename std::remove_const<T>::type> >(val);
    }
};

int main() {
    SomeClass<const int>x(5);
    SomeClass<int>y = x.other();
    return 0;
}
```